# prove MLE don't exist

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

so the pdf is
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\exp^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
$\mu$ and $\sigma$ are unknown,prove that they don't have MLE

it is a gaussian mixture model I guess? And I know there are no analytic solve for the derivative of log likehood function. But the text seems to mean that there are no numerical solve either. And I really don't know any methodology for prove MLE don't exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to prove that MLE doesn't exist is to show that the density or mass function doesn't have a global maxmium.

Here is the joint density function :
$$
\boldsymbol{f}_{\boldsymbol{X}_1,..,\boldsymbol{X}_{\boldsymbol{n}}}\left( \boldsymbol{x}_1,...,\boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{n}}|\boldsymbol{\mu },\boldsymbol{\sigma }^2 \right) =\prod_{\boldsymbol{i}=1}^{\boldsymbol{n}}{\left( \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\boldsymbol{\pi }}}\exp \left\{ -\frac{\boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{i}}^{2}}{2} \right\} +\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\boldsymbol{\pi }}\boldsymbol{\sigma }}\exp \left\{ -\frac{\left( \boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{i}}^{2}-\boldsymbol{\mu } \right) ^2}{2\boldsymbol{\sigma }^2} \right\} \right)}
$$

After observing the value of **X**, we have the Log likelihood:

$$
\boldsymbol{L}\left( \boldsymbol{\mu },\boldsymbol{\sigma }^2|\boldsymbol{x}_1,...,\boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{n}} \right) =\sum_{\boldsymbol{k}=1}^{\boldsymbol{n}}{\ln \left( \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\boldsymbol{\pi }}}\exp \left\{ -\frac{\boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{i}}^{2}}{2} \right\} +\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\boldsymbol{\pi }}\boldsymbol{\sigma }}\exp \left\{ -\frac{\left( \boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{i}}^{2}-\boldsymbol{\mu } \right) ^2}{2\boldsymbol{\sigma }^2} \right\} \right)}
$$
if **μ** happens to be the value of some **x**, for example, **μ** = **x1**, then we have:
$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{L}=&\,\,\underset{\boldsymbol{part}\,\,\boldsymbol{A}}{\underbrace{\ln \left( \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\boldsymbol{\pi }}}\exp \left\{ -\frac{\boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{i}}^{2}}{2} \right\} +\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\boldsymbol{\pi }}\boldsymbol{\sigma }} \right) }}
\\
&\,\,  +\underset{\boldsymbol{part}\,\,\boldsymbol{B}}{\underbrace{\sum_{\boldsymbol{k}=2}^{\boldsymbol{n}}{\ln \left( \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\boldsymbol{\pi }}}\exp \left\{ -\frac{\boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{i}}^{2}}{2} \right\} +\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\boldsymbol{\pi }}\boldsymbol{\sigma }}\exp \left\{ -\frac{\left( \boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{i}}^{2}-\boldsymbol{x}_1 \right) ^2}{2\boldsymbol{\sigma }^2} \right\} \right)}}}
\end{align}\\
$$

if we set **σ** → 0+:
$$
\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{part}\,\,\boldsymbol{A}&\rightarrow +\infty  
\\
\boldsymbol{part}\,\,\boldsymbol{B}&\rightarrow \sum_{\boldsymbol{k}=2}^{\boldsymbol{n}}{\ln \left( \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\boldsymbol{\pi }}}\exp \left\{ -\frac{\boldsymbol{x}_{\boldsymbol{i}}^{2}}{2} \right\} \right)}
\end{align}\\
$$

Thus you can say the Log likelihood doesn't have a global maxmium and the density function doesn't have a global maxmium and MLE equivalently.